# Activity se cierra al seleccionar item del listview

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un app de pedidos, logro cargar todo los productos de pedido, como no funcionaba el `setOnClickListener` de `listview`, coloque un `setOnClick listener` en el view del adapter, pero al mostrar un `alerdialog` se me cierra el activity, hago clic en un item del listview me muestra el alerdialog, al querer hacer clic en otro item se cierra.

Les pongo el código de mi Adapter.

```
    public class ProductosPedidoAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    TextView codigo, descripcion,cantidad,promocion;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    public ProductosPedidoAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_producto_pedido, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        try{
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            final TextView textomostrar = new TextView(context);
            codigo=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_productoCodigo_ped);
            descripcion=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_descripcion_ped);
            cantidad=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cantidad_ped);
            promocion=(TextView)view.findViewById((R.id.text_promocion_ped));
            String codproducto=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.detallePedido.DPcodproducto));
            codigo.setText(codproducto);
            descripcion.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.detallePedido.DPcodproducto)));
            cantidad.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.detallePedido.DPcantidad)));
            promocion.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.detallePedido.DPpromocion)));
            textomostrar.setText("Que desea realizar con el producto: "+codproducto);
            builder.setView(textomostrar).setTitle("Acciones");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Eliminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            builder.setNeutralButton("Actualizar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    builder.show();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("adapterpropedidos", "bindView: ",e );
        }

    }
}
```

El catch no captura nada.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Esto me muestra el log

```
05-19 15:25:14.576 17647-17647/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 
05-19 15:25:14.576 17647-17647/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false 
05-19 15:25:14.594 17647-17654/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe 
05-19 15:25:14.594 17647-17654/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active 
05-19 15:25:14.594 17647-17654/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation 
05-19 15:25:14.700 17647-17647/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.cspm.ventas6.cspm-2/lib/arm64 
05-19 15:25:14.701 17647-17647/? W/art: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits. 
05-19 15:25:14.707 17647-17647/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process 
05-19 15:25:14.725 17647-17647/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl 
05-19 15:25:14.736 17647-17647/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl 
05-19 15:25:14.748 17647-17647/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 
05-19 15:25:14.825 17647-17670/? I/loadProductos: codCabecera cp50587283 
05-19 15:25:14.831 17647-17647/? I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null 
05-19 15:25:14.834 17647-17647/? I/HwPointEventFilter: support AFT 
05-19 15:25:14.842 17647-17647/? I/HwPointEventFilter: support AFT 
05-19 15:25:14.844 17647-17647/? I/HwPointEventFilter: support AFT 
05-19 15:25:14.889 17647-17671/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 
05-19 15:25:14.893 17647-17671/? W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a 
05-19 15:25:14.936 17647-17647/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView

05-19 15:42:16.315 776-776/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 
05-19 15:42:16.315 776-776/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: Comparte el log del error que te muestra en la consola.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 0):

Para un listView utiliza setOnItemClickListener en vez de setOnClickListener.
Algo así:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

  //Hacer algo aquí

 }
```

Comment: Si lo utilice de esa manera y no fucionaba, no trabajaba

Answer (score 0):

Opino como @Adrià Moyá, lo mejor es que crees el evento onClick del listview así:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(onClickListView);  //Asignas el método al listview

//Declaras lo que quieres que haga el método
private ListView.OnItemClickListener onClickListView = new  ListView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                            long arg3)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Así debería hacerlo sin problemas, al menos te debería de entrar a este método al clickar sobre un elemento del listview.

No lo he puesto exactamente como @Adrià Moyà pero es lo mismo.